# Javascript form vaidation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am new to this forum and am quite a novice at Javascript:
I am trying to do a simple form validation.
On the head part of the html file I have a function

```
function form_onchange(){

    var Fname = document.getElementById('Fname');
    var RegExpTxt = /^([a-zA-Z ]){2,30}$/;

    if (!RegExpTxt(Fname.value)) {
        alert('Please provide a valid name');
        Fname.focus();
        Fname.select();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is just a part of the function I have other validation rules on it.

On the html part I have:

```
<table align="center" border = "1" bordercolor="#8B008B" cellpadding="5">
    <form action = "Pizza Fun.html" name = "formA" method = "post" onsubmit = "return checkBlank() ">
        <tr>
            <td><p>Name</p></td>
            <td><span>First </span><input type = "text" name = "Fname" id = "Fname" onchange = "form_onchange()" value = "first" />
            <span>Last </span><input type = "text" name = "Lname" id = "Lname" onchange = "form_onchange()" value = "lat " />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

The validation part was working yesterday but now for the life of me is not working now. Please can anyone help me why it is not working.

Comment: For sure '/^([a-zA-Z ]){2,30}$/.test("first")' gives true, so what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Use `RegExpTxt.test(Fname.value)` instead of `RegExpTxt(Fname.value)`

Javascript should end up being:

```
function form_onchange(){
    var Fname = document.getElementById('Fname');
    var RegExpTxt = /^([a-zA-Z ]){2,30}$/;
    if (!RegExpTxt.test(Fname.value)) {
    alert('Please provide a valid name');
    Fname.focus();
    Fname.select();
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have RegExpTxt.test(Fname.value) in my original code but I just forgot to put it down on the questions.  
It is still not working.

Comment: When I run he script and type illegitimate characters into the first name the alert pops up. So what doesn't work?